# Infopath button to start a workflow programmatically

Tags: workflow, infopath, sharepoint-server, submit

I have an infopath form to that has three (3) buttons in it. They are SAVE, SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL and CANCEL. When user presses SAVE it submits the form to the Sharepoint Library, when SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL button is pressed it submits the form to the Library and then starts a workflow that is present in the Library and CANCEL button to close the form without submission.

I want to embed a code in the SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL button which when pressed would automatically start the workflow. But I dont know where to start. I am so confused.. Someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't you just need a workflow that runs on the library when items change, then have it check for a status field on the form to see if it needs to run the submit for approval code ? Set the hidden status field on the InfoPath form with the button.

Comment: so the answer should've been: "infopath doesn't have such feature, here is a workaround..."